# Any way to add gems to specific environments using Rails Template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm building my Rails template right now. Rails template is a way to generate
a skeleton app.

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3
- http://m.onkey.org/2008/12/4/rails-templates

I would like to add some gems to test.rb and development.rb, but not environment.rb.
But I don't find a way to do so other than manually running Unix "echo" command to append
some snippets at the end of each file.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure,

```
config.gem "ruby-debug", :environment => [:development, :test]
```

hope this helps ;

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment the answer, so I complement with an answer:

with Rails 2.3.5, I had to use :env instead of :environment

> config.gem "ruby-debug", :env => :test